# How to let your manager know some of your colleagues are not the sharpest pencils in the box

Tags: colleagues, team, teamwork, performance

I have situations where time and again I encounter non-sense, non-high-standard behavior from some of my colleagues in the work.

These colleagues report to the same manager as me.

These can be ridiculous project plans, counter common-sense statements and activities, and more. They have a direct effect on the performance and work of the company.

To the best of my knowledge, the manager is not aware of these issues.

These issues are not new and happening for a long time - at least a few months.

I don't want to snitch on these people and tell the manager "Hi, you will NOT believe the  plan John just suggested!"

Should I tell him something or wait for him to find it out by himself?

Comment: Why is your manager not aware? The manager lacks the skillset to understand? They don't see the material?

Comment: In every discipline and every business there are people with varying levels of competence.  If you ever encounter a group where every pencil is sharp, stay there!  It will sharpen you.

Comment: When John suggests a bad plan, does the whole team just go with the bad plan or are you (or another colleague) able to convince enough people that it's bad? Are you just losing time discussing ideas or is work going out wrong? It's still not clear what the negative effect is.

Answer (score 10):

## Answer

Simply that you don't.

### Why not?

Your manager should be aware of the strengths and weaknesses of everyone in their team(s). They should know that Jane is great at project management but isn't great at API integration, or that Joe is brilliant at CSS but don't let him near a database. Further the manager should have a plan to help mitigate these issues and help their people grow where necessary.

### Ok, but I don't see why I shouldn't say anything?

Either:

- Your manager already knows and doesn't need you to tell them, you are just not aware of this

or

- You are telling your manager they are bad at their job

Neither of which will especially help the situation.

### Fine, but I really want to say something, when can I?

When your manager asks you directly for your honest opinion:

**Manager:** "Hey riorio, what do you think of Jane?"

**You:** "Oh she's a great at keeping her projects on track but I think she would benefit from some training on how to work with API's"

In this case be objective, be constructive and I'd also encourage you to be kind in your critique.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, everyone has dumb ideas sometimes. You aren't an exception, most probably. People misunderstand each other, "half knowledge" can be dangerous, and often you are the one who doesn't understand a measure you may call "ridiculous".

If it does not affect you personally, don't mention anything to your manager. If you think the colleague really has something wrong, give him a friendly heads up in private, or offer your help.

If it affects you, you can tell your manager. But please not like "Jimmy has made a really dumb decision. Because of that I won't meet my deadline".

Better:

Because of Project plan X I'm required to do Y. This will mean I will miss the Z deadline.

Don't point fingers. Ever.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally a bad idea to approach the situation with a "people" oriented solution. Yes your manager may take your opinion in account and do something, but unless you have great credibility and a good relation with your manager the best that will happen is a polite "thank you" or worse being reprimanded for overstepping your role and denigrating your peer.

In most cases it's not worth the effort to care about this. If it does impair your performance and this your evaluation and potential raise or promotion that is the issue you want to raise and solve.

If you really want to bring suggestions and try to improve the situation you will want to come prepared with "IMPACT" solutions. What problems did you see, what was the consequence (in $ or time), what solution you propose at which cost and what would it bring to the company (more $).

Answer (score 0):

**Do nothing**.  Your colleagues will sink or swim of their own volition.  If there's a vetting process, those ideas will not come to light unless it is foolproof.

Conversely, no plan is very bad or very good unless it's looked over thoroughly.  Perhaps collaboration and peer reviewing it with your colleague(s) would be more beneficial ("I like X, but I think Y and Z would be more time consuming, and W would break our budget.  How could we improve W, Y and Z?").